# JQuery-Mobile swipe doesn't work when you start on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have swipeleft/swiperight working well in my app but when the user does the mousedown over an anchor tag, the swiping action is not triggered.

How can I make the swipe work even when the user does the mousedown on an anchor tag?

EDIT: It looks like this is only an issue in browsers on computers - tablets work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can swipe with the normal left button in any modern browser on the desktop.

Make sure you prevent the default action on the dragstart event on your div.

```
$("div").bind('dragstart', function(event) {event.preventDefault(); });
```

I have a working copy here...

http://jsfiddle.net/38nXe/

Comment: Hmm... Doesn't work for me. I have carousel div > ul > li > a > img. 
Tried to prevent drag on each element in that tree. Seems other problem, it works if i unwrap images.

Comment: what browser are you using?  Can you post a js fiddle?

Comment: I changed the link above to a working jsfiddle.  Check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/38nXe/

Comment: I have posted the solution of my problem as additional answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can swipe on a desktop browser using the right mouse button.
It is not very elegant as it also opens the context menu. 
But it works everywhere.
Alex

Answer (score 0):

As for me it was caused "excludedElements", it filters all buttons, select, textarea, inputs and anchors.

To make it work add additional parameter with empty array for example.

$("#test").swipe({
    excludedElements:[]
  });

See touchSwipe plugin docs here [enter link description here](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/Excluded_children.html)